# What's the proper way of adding anchor links inside a php array?

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink

**I changed the single quotes to doubles quotes after I faced th following problem:**

```
 $lang = array(
        'let's do something...'
    );
```

**Now I have this problem:**

```
$lang = array(
    "tagline_h2" => "A paragraph...<a href="#">this is a link</a>"
);
```

What should I do?

Comment: You don't have to use the same kind of quote every time. You can use single quotes for a string with double quotes in, and double-quotes for a string with single quotes in! When you've got *both* kinds of quotes in a string, or when you need to use double quotes to get string interpolation, that's when you need to be thinking of backslash-escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are having double-quotes in a double-quoted string, you have to escape the double-quotes inside the string, using a backslash :

```
"A paragraph...<a href=\"#\">this is a link</a>"
```

See [Double quoted string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in the manual : it states that PHP will interpret the `\"` sequence as a double-quote *(and `\n` will interpreted as a newline, and there are a couple of other of those sequences)*

Answer (score 0):

I like to use urlencode() and urldecode() to store strings temporarily. That way I don't have to think about double-quotes, quotes, ampersands, newlines or tabs or in fact anything.

Two caveats:

- The academics will point out that it performs worse, and I would respond by saying that more time is wasted thinking about it than dealing with it, since it's a PHP website and not a particle accelerator. (Or is it?)
- You have to urldecode() it when you're going to show it.

PLEASE NOTE that for the problem you describe, urlencode()/urldecode() would be overkill. I only mentioned this for future reference, but in your particular case, the escaping is far more appropriate as described in the accepted solution.

Comment: Bloody hell, you're right, I completely misunderstood the problem. ;) Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, if you know that you are going to be dealing with quotes, why not use the [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntaxes?

That way, you can do:

```
$lang = array(
    "tagline_h2" => <<<LINK A paragraph...<a href="#">this is a link</a>
LINK
);
```